# Drag and Drop in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, tkinter

What is the correct/official/proper/recommended way of accomplishing drag/drop in tkinter? My documentation section 24.1.1 includes:

> Tkdnd Drag-and-drop support for Tkinter. This is experimental and
>   should become deprecated when it is replaced with the Tk DND.

but I can find no other *official* documentation. Does Tkinter have drag/drop support at all? Is this something version dependant? Is this something not yet included in tk(tcl) which will then filter through to tkinter?

I should stress that I am talking about drag/drop between different applications and that I am currently using python 2 (although any solution which relies on python 3 would still be of interest).

Comment: There's been some development - here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267900/python-drag-and-drop-explorer-files-to-tkinter-entry-widget

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tkinter has no built-in support for dragging and dropping between applications. Tkdnd is, AFAIK, the only way to accomplish it without writing the low level code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. From the quoted documentation, may I assume that _tkdnd_ and _tk dnd_ are two separate things?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this module](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py), D&D with TK and Python 3.

Comment: I know links aren't especially popular on SO, but this write-up was of great value figuring out how dnd works [Tkdnd](http://www.bitflipper.ca/Documentation/Tkdnd.html)