# Accessing the Windows mechanism that allows drag-and-drop between programs in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I can click-and-drag a link in Firefox down to my taskbar and place the cursor over the icon for Word, which will come to the foreground and allow me to drop the link into a Word document.

I need a Python program to be able to accept links in exactly the same way. What's the name of the system that allows this to happen (OLE?), and how can I access it from Python? Is there a platform-independent means to do so (that is, a similar system that will work on MacOS)?

Comment: Do you have a graphics toolkit you want to use, or are you looking for one that will do this?

Comment: This part of the Windows API looks relevant: [`DragAcceptFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WM_DROPFILES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). No idea how you'd use these in Python, though.

Comment: @SamMussmann Tkinter, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/dnd.html#interoperating-with-other-applications) from the QT site, it seems like OLE is the system that does drag and drop on Windows.

It looks like QT would provide the platform-independence that you want, since it implements appropriate protocols for Mac, Linux, and Windows.  You can use it from Python with [PyQt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/) or [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) (the official Python bindings for QT).  The differences between these two bindings are minimal, although the licenses are quite different.

I did do some searching around for Tkinter drag and drop stuff, and didn't find much (although I did find this question several times...).  There is an extension for Tk called [TkDND](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2768), and it is [possible to write Python extensions for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283431/600110).  However, development on this extension [does not seem active](http://sourceforge.net/p/tkdnd/svn/commit_browser), so I don't know how well it would work today in practice.

**TL;DR** Tkinter might work, but QT is a sure bet