# Make Tkinter Notebook be Draggable to Another View

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there is any `property` or `method` I could set to make `Tkinter` `Notebook` tabs draggable as another window, like `Sublime Text`. If not, I think I could write a function when the tab is dragged, but I don't know how to bind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any native properties for the ttk.Notebook widget but you could try Tkdnd.

There is some discussion of it here:
[How to Install and Use TkDnD with Python 2.7 Tkinter on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427347/how-to-install-and-use-tkdnd-with-python-2-7-tkinter-on-osx)
Which also links to:
[python drag and drop explorer files to tkinter entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267900/python-drag-and-drop-explorer-files-to-tkinter-entry-widget/14283431#14283431)