# Make Tkinter Notebook draggable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

A similar question was asked back in '15 [Make Tkinter Notebook be Draggable to Another View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129419/make-tkinter-notebook-be-draggable-to-another-view) but that was a while ago and that also asked about re-binding the window.

I was wondering how I would make a notebook draggable, even if is just to reorder the tabs.

Any advice would be helpful and please let me know if this question has been answered

Comment: Tab dragging has been implemented in tcl: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ttk::notebook, https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Drag+and+Drop+Notebook+Tabs. It can either be translated to python or evaluated through `.tk.eval()`.

Comment: And if you are interested in adding animations to the dragging (seeing the dragged tab move), I did this kind of thing but for dragging columns/rows of a treeview [here](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkwidgets/blob/master/ttkwidgets/table.py). Maybe it can help.

Comment: @j_4321 could you add those as answers? Could you also give more detail with `.tk.eval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab dragging has been implemented in TCL: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ttk::notebook, https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Drag+and+Drop+Notebook+Tabs. It can either be translated to python or evaluated through `.tk.eval()`.

For the second solution, one can put the TCL tab dragging code from the first link (except the last block which creates an example notebook) in a string and evaluate it with `root.tk.eval(TCL_CODE)`. Subsequently created notebooks will have tab dragging:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tcl_code = """
put here the code from the dragging tab code section of https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ttk::notebook
"""

root = tk.Tk()
root.tk.eval(tcl_code)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack()
for i in range(10):
    nb.add(ttk.Frame(nb, width=100, height=100), text=f"Tab {i}")

root.mainloop()
```

I also implemented tab dragging with animations (seeing the dragged tab move) as part of a larger project, the source code is available [here](https://github.com/j4321/PyTkEditor/blob/master/pytkeditorlib/gui_utils/notebook.py).