# Python Tkinter DnD2 root = TkinterDnD.Tk() Unable to load tkdnd library

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I installed TkDnD as instructed here: [How to Install and Use TkDnD with Python 2.7 Tkinter on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427347/how-to-install-and-use-tkdnd-with-python-2-7-tkinter-on-osx)

Mainly i followed this advice:

On Windows:

1) Copy the tkdnd2.8 directory to C:\Python27\tcl

2) Copy the TkinterDnD2 directory to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

I am using anaconda so I copied it into my environments directories (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\gui)

And yet when i try to run this code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *
from TkinterDnD2 import *

def drop(event):
    entry_sv.set(event.data)

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
entry_sv = StringVar()
entry_sv.set('Drop Here...')
entry = Entry(root, textvar=entry_sv, width=80)
entry.pack(fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)
entry.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
entry.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)
root.mainloop()
```

I get this error

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Unable to load tkdnd library.
  File "drag_and_drop_GUI.py", line 10, in <module>
    root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
```

Thinking it's a problem with anaconda I installed TkDnD in my system Python too (no virtual environments) but the issue still persists.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the library in your anaconda python installation? I thought the Anaconda interpreter and basic interpreter were separate?

Comment: Im pretty sure, I installed those 2 elements in these directories:
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\gui\tcl\tkdnd2.8
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\gui\Lib\site-packages\TkinterDnD2
I just called my env gui.
They are separate but I just installed Python that is separate from anaconda to check if conda is the problem.

Comment: Wait a second, you're importing FROM TkinterDnD2, what happens if you just instantiate Tk() instead of TkinterDnD2.Tk()?

Comment: I get a different error on a later line

entry.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)

Exception has occurred: _tkinter.TclError
invalid command name "tkdnd::drop_target"
  File "drag_and_drop_GUI.py", line 16, in <module>
    entry.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the tkdnd binary matching your python installation (64 bit or 32 bit).

Comment: making sure i installed the 64 bit version of tkdnd2.8 worked for me