# TkDnd working in Spyder but gives error after converting .exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I am creating one application which sorts files and merges them based filename. I needed filepaths when i drop files from file browser to my widget's listbox. For Tkinter i installed TkDnd. I followed instructions from [How to Install and Use TkDnD with Python 2.7 Tkinter on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427347/how-to-install-and-use-tkdnd-with-python-2-7-tkinter-on-osx) and it worked for me. I am using Anaconda and i paced folders in C:\Users\Anaconda3\tcl and C:\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages. I am using Spyder and python 3.7. I made executable from below command:

```
    pyinstaller --onefile -w PDF_Merger.py
```

After opening file it gives me error:

Fatal error ".py failed to execute"

I know this problem is regarding linking TkDnd.

I have tried making executable with --onedir and it still gives me error. But after copying tkdnd2.8 to dist it works.

Here is my code using TkDnd:

```
    from TkinterDnD2 import *

    widget = TkinterDnD.Tk()

    filesinfileslist = Variable(widget)
    FilesShow = ReorderableListbox(widget, font=('aerial',12), height = 23 , width = 45, listvariable = filesinfileslist,  selectmode = EXTENDED)
    FilesShow.place(x=10, y=40)
    FilesShow.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
    FilesShow.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)
```

drop method takes only pdf files and sets it to listBox.

As of now it works in spyder but .exe file gives me error. Can anyone show me how to resolve this issue or if i made some errors in code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with adding files from tkdnd2.8 folder with --add-data attribute while generating executable with pyinstaller. I was able to create it with onefile.

Answer (score 0):

This post is already a few years old but I got to it when I looked for my problem. In the end I solved it like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tkdnd2.8\;' myfile.py
```