# TkDnD Error: Unable to load tkdnd library (_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I am currently working on MacOs Catalina 10.15.6 with Python 3.8 and Tcl/Tk 8.6. As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427347/how-to-install-and-use-tkdnd-with-python-tkinter-on-osx), I donwloaded both the Tk extension **tkdnd2.8** from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdnd/ and the Python wrapper **TkinterDnD2** from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkinterdnd/, and then I copied the **tkdnd2.8** directory to **/Library/Tcl** and the **TkinterDnD2** directory to **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/.../lib/python/site-packages**.

After that, when trying to execute the following simple code:

```
from TkinterDnD2 import *
import tkinter as tk
root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
```

It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TkinterDnD2/TkinterDnD.py", line 39, in _require
        TkdndVersion = tkroot.tk.call('package', 'require', 'tkdnd')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Administrador/Desktop/tkdnd_test.py", line 3, in <module>
        root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TkinterDnD2/TkinterDnD.py", line 271, in __init__
        self.TkdndVersion = _require(self)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TkinterDnD2/TkinterDnD.py", line 41, in _require
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to load tkdnd library.')
RuntimeError: Unable to load tkdnd library.
```

Since tkdnd was not automatically being found/loaded (renaming the tkdnd2.8 folder to tkdnd didn't work either), I tried to manually specify the library path as suggested by @Ellis Shen and @aong152. I copied the **tkdnd2.8** folder next to my **tkdnd_test.py** file. Unfortunately, when running the following code:

```
from TkinterDnD2 import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys, os

print(os.environ.get('TKDND_LIBRARY'))
application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TK_DND_PATH = os.path.join(application_path,'tkdnd2.8')
os.environ['TKDND_LIBRARY'] = TK_DND_PATH
print(os.environ.get('TKDND_LIBRARY'))

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
```

The same error is displayed (before that, the tkdnd path is printed):

```
None
/Users/Administrador/Desktop/tkdnd2.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TkinterDnD2/TkinterDnD.py", line 39, in _require
        TkdndVersion = tkroot.tk.call('package', 'require', 'tkdnd')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Administrador/Desktop/tkdnd_test.py", line 11, in <module>
        root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TkinterDnD2/TkinterDnD.py", line 271, in __init__
        self.TkdndVersion = _require(self)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TkinterDnD2/TkinterDnD.py", line 41, in _require
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to load tkdnd library.')
RuntimeError: Unable to load tkdnd library.
```

I feel like I am missing something here, but I've spent a lot of time searching similar experiences and haven't been able to find a solution. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You might have a 32 bit library attempting to be loaded into a 64 bit python. Check the architecture for both.

Comment: @patthoyts I also thought that, but when I run `file libtkdnd2.8.dylib `, the output is: `libtkdnd2.8.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64] [i386:Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386]`. And when I run `python -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'` the output is `('7fffffffffffffff', True)` so I think they are both 64-bit. I also noticed that when i run the code in OS Mojave it just works fine, I only get the error in OS Catalina.

Comment: See my answer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427347/how-to-install-and-use-tkdnd-with-python-tkinter-on-osx/46856247#46856247

Comment: @Gary02127 yes, I used your answer bat had to modify some paths to make it work for macOS Catalina and above. You can see it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621610/14195896

Comment: @Gary02127, however, Eliav Louski has built it and uploaded it to pypi, so there is no need to install it manually anymore, pip install just works fine. Thanks Eliav!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [built](https://github.com/Eliav2/tkinterdnd2) it and upload it to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tkinterdnd2/)

you can now just do `pip install tkinterdnd2` and it should work.

import is `tkinterdnd2` and not `Tkinterdnd2`

Comment: I tried a fresh install on a new MacBook (with Intel and MacOs 11.2.3, not M1) and it worked perfectly with pip install! Thank you so much, you saved many struggling to a lot of people!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The folder where you should place the **tkdnd** library is **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/.../lib/**. Placing the lib on /Library/Tcl doesn't work for Catalina. I recommend you to install the newest tkdnd version (currently 2.9.3) available [here](https://github.com/petasis/tkdnd).