# (Pyinstaller) 'tclError: can't find package tkdnd' How can I fix this error?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to package my project into an executable file using pyinstaller. main.py, my program, should run when I run the exe file. Exe because program has to run somehow without the user, who is not a developer in any way, needing to install modules and python itself. If there's a better/easier way please do tell me.

i installed tkinterdnd2 by using `pip install tkinterdnd2`.

Not sure if this is necessary, but here is the directory of the program: (the pngs are only used for my program, I don't think that is the culprit):

```
Folder
- cardiologist.png
- img.png
    .
    . # a couple more pngs
    .
- main.py
- patients' data csv.csv
- patients' data xlsx test.xlsx
- sample.xlsx
- sun-valley.tcl #this file and the 'theme' folder below are for my program's theme, also don't think these are the culprit
- theme
    - dark
        - a lot of pngs...
    - dark.tcl
    - light
        - a lot of pngs...
    - light.tcl
```

Pyinstaller created 2 files, `build` and `dist` as expected.

```
build
    - main
        - base_library.zip
        - certifi
        - IPython
        - jedi
        - (some other files)
                .
                . a lot of .dylib files
                .
        - main    # exe file to execute to run program
        - matplotlib (this and next 4 are folders)
        - numpy
        - pandas
        - parso
        - PIL
        - Python  # exe file, don't know what this was created for
        - (some more folders)
        - tcl (this and next 2 are folders)
        - tcl8
            - 8.4
                - platform
                    - .tm file
                - .tm file
            - 8.5
                - 2 .tm files
            - 8.6
                - .tm file
                - tdbc
                    - .tm file
                - tkdnd2.8 (tried renaming to just tkdnd but same error)
        - tk
        - ttkwidgets
        - 2 other folders
```

The command I used:
`python -m PyInstaller main.py.    # without python -m, 'command not found error' would happen`

Error when running the produced exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py", line 53, in _require
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py", line 285, in __init__
  File "tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py", line 55, in _require
RuntimeError: Unable to load tkdnd library.
[7015] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I've went on the internet and tried looking for answers, but they either did not work for me, or wasn't clear enough like this: [*.py script with tkinterdnd2 module doesn`t compile to an executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702353/py-script-with-tkinterdnd2-module-doesnt-compile-to-an-executable-file) (this solution still gave me the same error).

I've also tried using other modules to package such as cx_freeze and py2app, but both produced a different error, so I went back to pyinstaller for now. I'm on macOS.

Any way to fix this error?

**EDIT**

also tried `python -m PyInstaller --clean -y -n "output_name" --add-data="tkdnd:tkdnd" main.py` but same error produced when running.

Comment: Try to use the library straight outta github https://github.com/petasis/tkdnd/tree/master/library

Comment: Since you installed `tkinterdnd2`, did you try `- tkinterdnd2` in your config file?

Comment: @PetrL. just tried downloading the whole zip from there, putting the whole folder into tcl 8.6 and even renaming it to `tkdnd`, same error still pops up. Putting it in the same directory as main produced the same error too.

Comment: @BryanOakley may I know what config file you are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

There is a section on `PyInstaller` in `tkinterdnd2` [website](https://pypi.org/project/tkinterdnd2/).

Basically the required steps are:

- copy `hook-tkinterdnd2.py` from the website to your project folder or create that file with below content:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = collect_data_files('tkinterdnd2')
```

- run `PyInstaller` as below:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py --additional-hooks-dir=.
```

Or based on the command in your question:

```
python -m PyInstaller -F main.py --additional-hooks-dir=.
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally made it work without manually moving folders.

```
pip install tkinterdnd2
```

I used auto py to exe and it didn't work with the "--add-binary" so I used "add-folder" in the gui, which is basically just "--add-data".

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/tkinterdnd2;tkinterdnd2/" "<your_script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Drag n Drop requires two components: the TCL libraries and the Tkinter interface to them. I install both manually to config my environment. (See my answer to  [How to Install and Use TkDnD with Python Tkinter on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427347/how-to-install-and-use-tkdnd-with-python-tkinter-on-osx/46856247#46856247)).  I know someone packaged something on PyPI for the TkinterDnD2, but I haven't looked into it.

I have a project which uses TkinterDnD2. I build it with PyInstaller and see the same error you see (more or less). Running PyInstaller with the --onedir option (rather than the --onefile option), I saw that `tkdnd2.8` was missing from my `dist` directory.

To rectify this, on Windows, I added

```
--add-binary "C:/Python/Python38-32/tcl/tkdnd2.8;tkdnd2.8"
```

to the PyInstaller command line, and that did the trick. I can now build a --onefile executable, and it runs without error.

You tried something similar, but I used the --add-binary rather than --add-data, and I give the full path to the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the first hand experience of the other answers, but I personally distribute tkdnd in my applications. Granted, I first did this before `tkinterdnd2` was available in PyPi. I used both the tkdnd distribution along with the python wrapper.
In my build script, I have

```py
copy_tree('build_files/tkdnd2.9.2', os.path.dirname(sys.executable) + '/tcl/tkdnd2.9.2')
copy_tree('build_files/TkinterDnD2', os.path.dirname(sys.executable) + '/Lib/site-packages/TkinterDnD2')
```

And in my spec file,

```py
tkdnd = [(os.path.abspath(file), 'tkdnd2.9.2') for file in iglob('build_files/tkdnd2.9.2/*.*')]
data_files = [...] + tkdnd
a = Analysis9(..., datas=data_files,...)
```

You can further take a look at the my project, [Music Caster](https://github.com/elibroftw/music-caster)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked (thanks to Hamet). I just want to post this because on Windows 11 I found that the path to the tkinterdnd2 package files is slightly different, at least in my case.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "[path-to-python]\Lib\site-packages\TkinterDnD2\tkdnd\win64;TkinterDnD2" "[my-script-name].py"
```

Also, I had to capitalise the package name itself - I guess it must be the same as the package name in the import statement at the top of the script? "from TkinterDnD2 import *"