# PyInstaller + tkdnd/tkinterdnd2 "Unable to load tkdnd library" when launching frozen exe. Works when launched from script

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

In my script I am using `tkinterdnd2` library to achieve drag and drop functionality from Windows explorer into my tkinter UI.

```
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES
import tkinter as tk

class TkWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = TkinterDnD.Tk()
        self.tbox = tk.Listbox(self.window)
        self.tbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.tbox.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
        self.tbox.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', self.tk_files_dropped)
        self.window.mainloop()

    def tk_files_dropped(self, event):
        messagebox.showinfo("x", event.data)

TkWindow()
```

When I launch the script - everything works.

But when I freeze the project to a single EXE with PyInstaller, and run it, I get this error:

[image: Unable to load tkdnd library.]

I tried this solutions already:

1. I added the pyinstaller-hook [as instructed](https://github.com/Eliav2/tkinterdnd2#pyinstaller) in the `tkinterdnd2` repository:

   `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files, eval_statement`
   `datas = collect_data_files('tkinterdnd2')`
2. I add `--collect-all tkinterdnd2` when executing build command.
3. I tried copying `tkdnd2.8` to `tcl8.6` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68702416/1078466)
4. I tried getting rid of venv and installing all the packages directly into base python interpreter.

Comment: when I was having issues with pyinstaller, I tried different methods which didn't work until I run pip uninstall typing in command prompt and it worked fine.

Comment: @CEO do you mean uninstalling and installing pyinstaller? Tried that too.

Comment: not really. Let me write it in the answer section then

Comment: Does your code run without any error in the code editor?

Comment: Yes. Without any error. Full repo is here: https://github.com/deshudiosh/PyWykladzinyLayout

Answer (score 3):

I used `--collect-all TkinterDnD2` with upperCase.

Comment: I already switched to wxpython but I am glad you answered. Seams that this might be the reason.

Comment: I had to make it lower case.  The full command I used was, `python -m PyInstaller --noconsole -F --collect-all TkinterDnD2 main.py`

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Python file to an exe, run `pyinstaller.exe --collect-all TkinterDnD2 --windowed yor_app.py`. This will create files and folders of the program that was created. You will find a file named TCL. Copy the tkdnd folder into it and then run the exe file

Comment: pyinstaller.exe --collect-all TkinterDnD2 --windowed yor_app.py

Comment: Doesn't the other answer already cover this? In any case, please mark code with backticks (`\``), not parentheses. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting