# When exporting python file to exe, it doesn't run properly.(can't find package tkdnd)

Tags: python

**I am a Python learner.**

I wrote a code that works well for reading PDFs at night.
The code that imports the library is as follows(The full code I will put at the end):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import DND_FILES, TkinterDnD
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, simpledialog
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageTk
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import threading
```

My installation package is shown in Pycharm as follows:

[The package in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/042Rx.png)

At the same time when processing PDF this code needs to use the poppler (the folder called bin)  (I put it in the same directory as the .py file in the same directory)

[My folder information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTy5g.png)

And in my code, I locate the folder bin in the following way:

[The  locating way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtd0X.png)

After I tried the following:

```
Pyinstaller -F -w -p Lib/site-packages --add-data "bin;bin" PDF_Night_reading.py
```

[The process I run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9XXi.png)

The exe I got to run in dist resulted in the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsWqU.png)

My complete code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import DND_FILES, TkinterDnD
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, simpledialog
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageTk
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import threading


class PDFNightModeConverter:
    def __init__( self, root ):
       self.root = root
       self.root.title( 'PDF夜间阅读模式转化' )
       self.output_pdf_path = ""
       self.export_pdf_path = ""  # 用于存储导出路径
       self.poppler_path = "./bin"
       self.chosen_gray_value = 49  # 默认灰度值
       self.processing = False  # 文件是否正在处理
       self.preview_image = None  # 用于在Canvas上显示的PIL图像
       self.setup_ui( )
    
    
    
    def process_page( self, img, output_images, index, lock ):
       img_gray = img.convert( "L" )
       img_inverted = ImageOps.invert( img_gray )
       data = np.array( img_inverted )
       
       low_gray_mask = data < self.chosen_gray_value  #低于选择值的像素变为选择值
       data[low_gray_mask] = self.chosen_gray_value
       
       high_gray_mask = data >= 200  #高于选择值的像素变为固定值
       data[high_gray_mask] = 240
       
       img_modified = Image.fromarray( data )
       with lock:
          output_images[index] = img_modified
    
    def setup_ui( self ):
       text_color = '#000000'  # 黑色字体
       bg_color = '#FFFFFF'  # 白色背景
       self.lbl_color_prompt = tk.Label( self.root, text = "请选择转换后的背景亮度", bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       self.lbl_color_prompt.pack( pady = (20, 0) )
       
       self.color_frame = tk.Frame( self.root, bg = bg_color )
       self.color_frame.pack( pady = 10 )
       
       btn_color1 = tk.Button( self.color_frame, text = '  ', bg = '#20201f',\
                               width = 5, command = lambda:self.choose_color( 31 ) )
       btn_color1.pack( side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10 )
       
       btn_color2 = tk.Button( self.color_frame, text = '  ', bg = '#313233',\
                               width = 5, command = lambda:self.choose_color( 49 ) )
       btn_color2.pack( side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10 )
       
       lbl_color_choice = tk.Label( self.root, text = "(左偏暗,右偏亮,不选默认为右)", bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       lbl_color_choice.pack( pady = (5, 20) )
       
       # 文件选择框
       file_frame = tk.Frame( self.root, bg = bg_color )
       file_frame.pack( pady = 10 )
       
       self.entry_filename = tk.Entry( file_frame, width = 50, bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       self.entry_filename.pack( side = tk.LEFT, padx = (0, 10) )
       self.entry_filename.insert( 0, "选择文件路径" )
       
       btn_select = tk.Button( file_frame, text = "选择", command = self.select_file, bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       btn_select.pack( side = tk.LEFT )
       
       # 导出路径选择框
       export_file_frame = tk.Frame( self.root, bg = bg_color )
       export_file_frame.pack( pady = 10 )
       
       self.entry_export_filename = tk.Entry( export_file_frame, width = 50, bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       self.entry_export_filename.pack( side = tk.LEFT, padx = (0, 10) )
       self.entry_export_filename.insert( 0, "导出文件路径(不选则与原文件处于同一目录)" )
       
       btn_export_select = tk.Button( export_file_frame, text = "选择",\
                                      command = self.select_export_path, bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       btn_export_select.pack( side = tk.LEFT )
       
       # 添加一个标签用于显示文字"预览"
       self.lbl_preview = tk.Label( self.root, text = "预览", bg = 'white' )
       self.lbl_preview.pack( pady = (10, 0) )
       
       # 修改选择页数按钮位置
       self.btn_choose_page = tk.Button( self.root, text = "选择页数", command = self.choose_page )
       self.btn_choose_page.pack( )
       
       # "开始处理"按钮
       self.btn_start = tk.Button( self.root, text = "开始处理", command = self.start_processing, bg = bg_color,
                                   fg = text_color )
       self.btn_start.pack( side = tk.LEFT, padx = (0, 10) )
       
       # 状态标签
       self.lbl_status = tk.Label( self.root, text = "", bg = bg_color, fg = text_color )
       self.lbl_status.pack( ipadx = 10, ipady = 10, fill = 'x' )
       self.btn_open_folder = tk.Button( self.root, text = "打开文件所在目录",\
                                         command = self.open_output_directory )
       # 注意：这个按钮暂时还没有放入布局中
    
    def update_preview( self, page_num ):
       try:
          # 载入PDF的指定页码
          pdf_path = self.entry_filename.get( )
          pdf_page = convert_from_path( pdf_path, first_page = page_num, last_page = page_num,
                                        poppler_path = self.poppler_path )[0]
          
          # 处理页面
          img_gray = pdf_page.convert( "L" )
          img_inverted = ImageOps.invert( img_gray )
          data = np.array( img_inverted )
          
          low_gray_mask = data < self.chosen_gray_value  #低于选择值的像素变为选择值
          data[low_gray_mask] = self.chosen_gray_value
          
          high_gray_mask = data >= 200  #高于选择值的像素变为固定值
          data[high_gray_mask] = 240
          
          img_modified = Image.fromarray( data )
          
          # 将图像调整到Canvas的大小
          self.preview_image_full_size = img_modified  # 保存完整尺寸的图像副本
          img_modified.thumbnail( (self.preview_canvas.winfo_width( ), self.preview_canvas.winfo_height( )),
                                  Image.Resampling.LANCZOS )
          
          # 将处理后的图像转换为Tkinter兼容的图片
          self.preview_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage( image = img_modified )
          
          # 在Canvas上展示图片，并绑定点击事件
          self.preview_canvas.create_image(
             0,
             0,
             anchor = 'nw',
             image = self.preview_image
          )
          self.preview_canvas.config( scrollregion = self.preview_canvas.bbox( 'all' ) )
          self.preview_canvas.bind( "<Button-1>", self.popup_image )  # 点击图像时触发popup_image
       except Exception as e:
          messagebox.showerror( "错误", str( e ) )
    
    def choose_color( self, gray_value ):
       self.chosen_gray_value = gray_value
       self.lbl_status.config( text = f"选定亮度: {self.chosen_gray_value}" )
       self.root.configure( bg = self.gray_to_hex( gray_value ) )  # 改变窗口背景颜色PDF_Night_reading
    
    def gray_to_hex( self, gray_value ):
       hex_value = format( gray_value, 'x' )
       return f'#{hex_value}{hex_value}{hex_value}'
    
    def select_file( self ):
       file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename( )
       if file_path:
          self.entry_filename.delete( 0, tk.END )
          self.entry_filename.insert( 0, file_path )
          self.lbl_status.config( text = "" )
    
    def choose_page( self ):
       page_num = simpledialog.askinteger( "选择页数", "请输入想要预览的页数:", parent = self.root )
       if page_num is not None:
          if 1 <= page_num:  # 假设没有最大页数限制
             self.selected_page = page_num
             self.show_page_in_window( page_num )  # 在新窗口中显示所选页面
    
    def show_page_in_window( self, page_num ):
       try:
          pdf_path = self.entry_filename.get( )
          pdf_page = convert_from_path( pdf_path, first_page = page_num, last_page = page_num,
                                        poppler_path = self.poppler_path )[0]
          
          img_gray = pdf_page.convert( "L" )
          img_inverted = ImageOps.invert( img_gray )
          data = np.array( img_inverted )
          
          low_gray_mask = data < self.chosen_gray_value
          data[low_gray_mask] = self.chosen_gray_value
          
          high_gray_mask = data >= 200
          data[high_gray_mask] = 240
          
          img_modified = Image.fromarray( data )
          
          # 创建一个新窗口
          top = tk.Toplevel( )
          top.title( "Page Preview" )
          
          # 获取原始图像的尺寸
          width, height = img_modified.size
          
          # 在新窗口中添加滚动条
          scrollbar_vert = tk.Scrollbar( top, orient = "vertical" )
          scrollbar_hor = tk.Scrollbar( top, orient = "horizontal" )
          
          # 添加一个Canvas来显示图像，并配置滚动条
          canvas = tk.Canvas( top, width = width, height = height, yscrollcommand = scrollbar_vert.set,
                              xscrollcommand = scrollbar_hor.set )
          scrollbar_vert.config( command = canvas.yview )
          scrollbar_hor.config( command = canvas.xview )
          
          # 打包Canvas和滚动条到窗口中
          canvas.pack( side = tk.LEFT, expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH )
          scrollbar_vert.pack( side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y )
          scrollbar_hor.pack( side = tk.BOTTOM, fill = tk.X )
          
          img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage( image = img_modified )
          canvas.create_image( 0, 0, anchor = "nw", image = img_tk )
          canvas.config( scrollregion = canvas.bbox( "all" ) )
          
          # 保存 img_tk 到类的属性，以防止它被垃圾回收
          self.img_tk = img_tk
          
          # 函数：用于Windows和MacOS鼠标滚轮事件处理
          def on_mousewheel( event ):
             canvas.yview_scroll( int( -1 * (event.delta / 120) ), "units" )
          
          # 函数：用于Linux鼠标滚轮向上滚动事件处理
          def on_linux_scroll_up( event ):
             canvas.yview_scroll( -1, "units" )
          
          # 函数：用于Linux鼠标滚轮向下滚动事件处理
          def on_linux_scroll_down( event ):
             canvas.yview_scroll( 1, "units" )
          
          # 绑定鼠标滚轮事件
          top.bind( "<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel )  # 对于Windows和MacOS
          top.bind( "<Button-4>", on_linux_scroll_up )  # 对于Linux向上滚动
          top.bind( "<Button-5>", on_linux_scroll_down )  # 对于Linux向下滚动
       
       except Exception as e:
          messagebox.showerror( "错误", str( e ) )
    
    def select_export_path( self ):
       export_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename( defaultextension = ".pdf" )
       if export_path:
          self.entry_export_filename.delete( 0, tk.END )
          self.entry_export_filename.insert( 0, export_path )
          self.export_pdf_path = export_path
    
    def open_output_directory( self ):
       if os.path.exists( self.output_pdf_path ):
          os.startfile( os.path.dirname( self.output_pdf_path ) )
       else:
          messagebox.showinfo( "信息", "文件不存在。" )
    
    def start_processing( self ):
       file_path = self.entry_filename.get( )
       if file_path and not self.processing:
          self.lbl_status.config( text = "正在处理..." )
          self.processing = True
          self.btn_start.config( state = "disabled" )  # 禁用按钮
          threading.Thread( target = self.process_pdf_multithreaded, args = (file_path,), daemon = True ).start( )
          self.disable_buttons( )  # 禁用所有按钮
    
    def preview_page( self, page_num ):
       # 检查是否有可用的PDF页面图像
       if not hasattr( self, 'pdf_images' ) or not self.pdf_images:
          messagebox.showinfo( "错误", "没有可预览的文件。" )
          return
       if page_num - 1 < len( self.pdf_images ):
          img = self.pdf_images[page_num - 1]  # 获取正确的页面图像
          img_processed = self.process_page_for_preview( img )  # 处理图像以预览
          self.display_image_on_canvas( img_processed )  # 在 Canvas 上显示图像
    
    def process_page_for_preview( self, img ):
       img_gray = img.convert( "L" )
       img_inverted = ImageOps.invert( img_gray )
       data = np.array( img_inverted )
       
       low_gray_mask = data < self.chosen_gray_value
       data[low_gray_mask] = self.chosen_gray_value
       
       high_gray_mask = data >= 200
       data[high_gray_mask] = 240
       
       img_modified = Image.fromarray( data )
       img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage( image = img_modified )
       return img_tk
    
    def display_image_on_canvas( self, img_tk ):
       self.preview_canvas.delete( "all" )  # 清除Canvas上的内容
       self.preview_canvas.create_image( 0, 0, anchor = "nw", image = img_tk )
       self.preview_canvas.image = img_tk  # 避免图像被垃圾收集器回收
    
    def process_pdf_multithreaded( self, pdf_path ):
       try:
          images = convert_from_path( pdf_path, poppler_path = self.poppler_path )
          output_images = [None] * len( images )
          threads = []
          lock = threading.Lock( )
          
          for index, img in enumerate( images ):
             thread = threading.Thread( target = self.process_page, args = (img, output_images, index, lock) )
             threads.append( thread )
             thread.start( )
          
          for thread in threads:
             thread.join( )
          
          if self.export_pdf_path:
             self.output_pdf_path = self.export_pdf_path
          else:
             self.output_pdf_path = os.path.splitext( pdf_path )[0] + "_DarkRead.pdf"
          
          if output_images:
             output_images[0].save( self.output_pdf_path, "PDF", resolution = 100.0,\
                                    save_all = True, append_images = output_images[1:] )
          
          self.root.after( 0, self.update_ui_post_processing )
       except Exception as e:
          self.root.after( 0, messagebox.showerror, "错误", str( e ) )
          self.root.after( 0, self.lbl_status.config, { "text":"文件处理失败" } )
          self.root.after( 0, self.reset_processing_state )
    
    def update_ui_post_processing( self ):
       self.lbl_status.config( text = "文件处理已完成" )
       self.btn_open_folder.pack( pady = (5, 20) )
       self.reset_processing_state( )
    
    def reset_processing_state( self ):
       self.processing = False
       self.enable_buttons( )  # 启用所有按钮
    
    def disable_buttons( self ):
       self.btn_start.config( state = "disabled" )
       self.btn_choose_page.config( state = "disabled" )
       # 禁用其他所有按钮
    
    def enable_buttons( self ):
       self.btn_start.config( state = "normal" )
       self.btn_choose_page.config( state = "normal" )
       # 启用其他所有按钮


# 创建主窗口
root = TkinterDnD.Tk( )
app = PDFNightModeConverter( root )
root.mainloop( )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main( )
```

***I've tried a lot of things since then, but the best I've gotten is the constant error in the exe.***

What can I do to get Exe works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem was described at this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69348567/pyinstaller-tkdnd-tkinterdnd2-unable-to-load-tkdnd-library-when-launching-fr/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69348567/pyinstaller-tkdnd-tkinterdnd2-unable-to-load-tkdnd-library-when-launching-fr).

The solution was to add the `--collect-all TkinterDnD2` flag when starting PyInstaller. In your case full command will be

```bash
pyinstaller -F -w -p Lib/site-packages --add-data "bin;bin" --collect-all TkinterDnD2 PDF_Night_reading.py
```

I copied the rest of the flags from your screenshot.

Comment: THX,bro,Things got better when I followed your instructions
(But I noticed in my code that the package I imported was named **"tkinterdnd2"**)
(so I ended up typing 
```pyinstaller -F -w -p Lib/site-packages --add-data "bin;bin" --collect-all tkinterdnd2 py_convert_exe.py```
in cmd)