# Drag and drop files onto a Tkinter Gui

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

**Assumption:** I'm using Python 3.6 and I'm working on Windows 10

Is possible to create a **GUI** with **tkinter** in which dragging a file in the window it returns the path of the file?

If with tkinter it's not possible, is there another solution that can solve the problem without installing additional libraries?

Comment: No, that's not possible, you'll need to install TkinterDnD2 as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865239/4014959

Comment: In the link's answer, he talks about Python 2.6 and OsX, but nothing that could be useful for me

Comment: Does windows send a broadcast when the user try to use the drag n' drop system?
EDIT: Is possible to get it via sys?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Windows. According to http://tkinterdnd.sourceforge.net/ TkinterDnD2 works with Windows, Unix and Mac OSX, with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install tkinterdnd2

```
pip install tkinterdnd2
```

code:

```
from tkinter import TOP, Entry, Label, StringVar
from tkinterdnd2 import *


def get_path(event):
    pathLabel.configure(text = event.data)

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.geometry("350x100")
root.title("Get file path")

nameVar = StringVar()

entryWidget = Entry(root)
entryWidget.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

pathLabel = Label(root, text="Drag and drop file in the entry box")
pathLabel.pack(side=TOP)

entryWidget.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
entryWidget.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", get_path)

root.mainloop()
```