# How to get filepaths properly from tkinterDND2 event object

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to implement "drop files here" feature in a simple GUI application using tkinter in python

It uses the TkinterDnD2 which is ended up by seeing this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267900/python-drag-and-drop-explorer-files-to-tkinter-entry-widget)

Upon dropping the file event.data returns file name surrounded with curly braces

Example: `{d:/test/sample1.pdf}`

However when multiple files are dropped in the target each path is surrounded by curly braces

Example: `{D:/test/sample1.pdf} {D:/test/sample2.pdf}`

How to properly parse the file paths from this string?

Comment: Post the code you have written . Else first code it and edit the post with your code

Comment: The examples are the strings that the event.data returns.. that is.. each path is surrounded by curly braces.. I want to extract just the path from that string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using this two lines of python code:

```
temp = filePathsReturned[1:-1]
list = temp.split("} {")
```

Comment: Yeah that works well carry on. My answer works well if there are no gaps between paths and as well there are multiple {} curly braces as highlighted in my answer

Comment: actually this answer is only a derivative from your answer..thank you so much for providing the insight

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether TkinterDnD2 library will return a stream of paths in a single string or single path in a string.

If it is single path in a string the solution is simple:

```
>>> str1="{mypath/to/file}"
>>> str1[1:-1]
```

The output would be

```
'mypath/to/file'
```

But I suppose your problem is multiple paths coming in single string. You can implement code as below.

Consider str1 to be string with multiple paths:

```
str1="{mypath1/tofile1}{mypath3/tofile3}{mypath2/tofile2}"
i=0
patharr=[]
while(str1.find('{',i)>=0):
    strtIndex=str1.find('{',i)
    if(str1.find('}',strtIndex+1)>0):
        endIndex=str1.find('}',strtIndex+1)
        patharr.append(str1[strtIndex+1:endIndex])
        print(str1[strtIndex:endIndex+1])
        i=endIndex+1
print(patharr)
```

Now the output would be as follows:

> ['mypath1/tofile1', 'mypath3/tofile3', 'mypath2/tofile2']

So as per your question in comment below is code for file paths which are having curly braces with in the file paths.

```
str1 = "{mypath}}}}1/tofil{{{e1}{mypath3/tofile3}{mypath2/tofile2}}}}}}"
i = 0
patharr = []
while (str1.find('{', i) >= 0):
    strtIndexfirst = str1.find('{', i)
    notFound = True
    strtIndex = strtIndexfirst
    while (notFound and strtIndex < len(str1)):

        if (str1.find('}', strtIndex + 1) > 0):
            findInd = str1.find('}', strtIndex + 1)

            if (findInd == len(str1) - 1):
                endIndex = str1.find('}', strtIndex + 1)
                patharr.append(str1[strtIndexfirst + 1:endIndex])
                print(str1[strtIndex:endIndex + 1])
                i = endIndex + 1
                break
            if (str1[findInd + 1] == '{'):
                endIndex = str1.find('}', strtIndex + 1)
                patharr.append(str1[strtIndexfirst + 1:endIndex])
                print(str1[strtIndex:endIndex + 1])
                i = endIndex + 1

                notFound = False
            else:
                strtIndex = findInd
        else:
            strtIndex = str1.find('}', strtIndex + 1)

print(patharr)
```

For above string output was

> ['mypath}}}}1/tofil{{{e1', 'mypath3/tofile3', 'mypath2/tofile2}}}}}']

If str1 is

```
str1="{{{mypath1/tofil}}e1}{mypath3/tofile3}{mypath2/tofile2}}}}}}"
```

Output is

> ['{{mypath1/tofil}}e1', 'mypath3/tofile3', 'mypath2/tofile2}}}}}']

Worked out for other test cases as well. This piece of code is working fine.

Comment: I thought of doing something like this..but it might become an issue if the file name has curly braces in them..

Comment: @DivakarRajesh please check now Edited and updated answer

Comment: This doesn't work out for `{C:/Users/DivakarRajesh/Desktop/Coders/Basic Programming Concepts using C/utility-programs-in-python/Working with PDF/sample2.pdf} {C:/Users/DivakarRajesh/Desktop/Coders/Basic Programming Concepts using C/utility-programs-in-python/Working with PDF/test.pdf} {C:/Users/DivakarRajesh/Desktop/Coders/Basic Programming Concepts using C/utility-programs-in-python/Working with PDF/sample1.pdf}`

Comment: There are gaps between path end } and path start {. This is not expected. This is again lot of work. May be will help you later.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort. I have solved it myself

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but there's a better built in solution.  The event.data is a Tk list, and there's a splitlist() method provided by Tk in Python. I updated the code from the OP's linked question ([Drag and drop explorer files to tkinter entry widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267900/python-drag-and-drop-explorer-files-to-tkinter-entry-widget)) with a function that turns the event data into a list and adds it to the listbox

```
def handle_drop(event):
    for f in root.tk.splitlist(event.data):
        lb.insert(tk.END, f)
```

The complete example is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import DND_FILES, TkinterDnD

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()  # notice - use this instead of tk.Tk()
lb = tk.Listbox(root)
lb.insert(1, "drag files to here")

# register the listbox as a drop target
lb.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)

def handle_drop(event):
    for f in root.tk.splitlist(event.data):
        lb.insert(tk.END, f)

lb.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', handle_drop)

lb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```