# Tkinter Drop Zone - moving beyond pyperclip?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to improve a little automation program that I have written, which uses pyperclip. I would like to be able to get the filename(s) and path(s) of a file, directory or group of files dragged into a GUI window.

I have been playing with tkinter, and see that there is a `tkinter.dnd` method, though I am not seeing any great documentation on how to make it work. And the few that I have found, don't work as I was hoping. Thank you for any insight!

Comment: [python drag and drop explorer files to tkinter entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267900/python-drag-and-drop-explorer-files-to-tkinter-entry-widget)

Comment: I will check the link out. Thanks