# Is there a way to upload files with tkinter in python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am making a system to upload file for an AI project, so it will be both text files and image files. Is there a way to select files by dragging and dropping into a tkinter window, like how you can in GitHub? And is there a way to open a file browser window to select the files?

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267900/drag-and-drop-explorer-files-to-tkinter-entry-widget

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can open a file browser window to select the files.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def getLocalFile():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    filePath=filedialog.askopenfilename()

    print('File path：',filePath)
    return filePath

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getLocalFile()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I meant when I said open a file browser window!

Comment: Is there a way to upload multiple files at once?

Comment: Yeah, cur=filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[('text files', '.txt'),('pythonfiles',('.py','.pyw'))])

Comment: It's will return a tuple. The contents of tuple is file paths.